# Cannot write code when running AVD

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I run AVD but after that my cursor is always being refreshed. It makes me can't do coding while the AVD is running.

I should close the AVD and make code changes and then back to run it again after coding.

Any helps?

Comment: isn't it called `lagging` of a system ?

Comment: @HeisenBrg, I don't think so. because the refreshing time is only 1-2 sec and then stop after I put cursor and ready to write code, it is being refreshed for 1-2 sec again.

Comment: What system are you using ?

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.4, React-Native 0.55, Windows 10 x64

Comment: my code was created from react-native cli 2.0.1. and code I run is initial code

Answer (score 0):

Open react-native [developer menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html) and disable the Live Reload